# How to override a single file using module deployment?

Tags: module, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using alfresco sdk 2.0.0 which have alfresco share version 5.1.e

This my code to override/replace OOTB file using modules

```
  <module>
   <id>Highlight Query Text</id>
   <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>
   <description>Highlight text in web previewer</description>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <customizations>
     <customization>
       <targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco.components.preview</targetPackageRoot>
       <sourcePackageRoot>com.some.components.preview</sourcePackageRoot>
      </customization>
     </customizations>
  </module>
```

In `<targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco.components.preview</targetPackageRoot>`

This overrides/replaces site-webscripts/**org/alfresco/components/preview** folder with site-webscripts/**com/some/components/preview**

Is there any way to override only single file ? like : `\org\alfresco\components\preview\web-preview.get.html.ftl` with `com\some\components\preview\web-preview.get.html.ftl`

Answer (score 1):

Only the files located in the `sourcePackageRoot` will override the default ones, so in your case, only add your `web-preview.get.html.ftl` in the `com\some\components\preview` package.

Comment: You are right ,  but I don't know why if I adds this file web-preview.get.html.ftl only then nothing get reflactes , if I adds web-preview.get.config.xml and web-preview.get.js also - config and js both then it works perfectly.